# for loop fails to iterate more than 49 times

Tags: android, for-loop

(Been a week since) I'm trying to do some stuff in a for loop. **I realised `for` loop doesn't run 50th+ iterations**.
On a button Click:

```
for(int i=0;i<70;i++){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Hi"+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

This Toast is shown for upto 49 only. **How do I run it till 69 or any number greater than 49?**

Comment: The for loop _is_ looping correctly. It's just that the toasts won't show up. Why do you want to do 70 toasts all at once?

Comment: Try logging the value inside the loop.
for(int i=0;i<70;i++) {
    System.out.println("Hi " + i);
}

Comment: yes, follow ADM's answer below: use `Log.d` for debugging, not any `Toast`s

Comment: Yes. Everyone's right. I just wated a week cos Toasts have some problem. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loop is not failed. Its not a good idea to show `Toast`  on each iteration . Try to log the iteration. Check `debug` logs.

```
for(int i=0;i<70;i++){
        Log.d("Iteration","Hi"+i);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to Use API's such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask For Longer Background Process.